# OOP PHP - Correct way to extend classes and call the methods

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to create my first classes in PHP.

The below ones work fine and as expected. But as I know there is a way to `extend` a class an call the methods directly.
So I am thinking that maybe the following code even if it works is a bad one.
I am looking to understand how to achieve the same result but with a correct way of coding.
Thanks for any suggestion:

```
$game = new game();

$select = $game->db->select('users', '*');
print_r($select);
```

The above selects data from the DB and it is correctly returning the values.

This is the game class:

```
class game {
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new db();
    }

}
```

This is the DB class, that for now it is inserted in the contruct of the game class, but I need to know if this is correct way of coding or if I should extend the class or whatever:

```
class db {

    private $options;
    private $pdo;

    function __construct() {
        $this->options = array(
            'database_host' => DATABASE_HOST,
            'database_name' => DATABASE_NAME,
            'database_user' => DATABASE_USER,
            'database_pass' => DATABASE_PASS
        );

        $this->connect();

    }

    private function connect() {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->options['database_host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->options['database_name'], $this->options['database_user'], $this->options['database_pass']);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->exec("set names utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function select($table, $what, $where = NULL, $custom = NULL) {
        $query = "SELECT " . $what . " FROM " . $table;
        $child = "1";
        $param = array();
        if ($where)
            foreach ($where as $data => $value) {
                if ($child == "1") {
                    $query .= " WHERE " . $data . " = '" . $value . "'";
                    $param[":" . $data] = $value;
                    $child = "next";
                } else {
                    $query .= " AND " . $data . " = '" . $value . "'";
                    $param[":" . $data] = $value;
                }
            }

        if ($custom)
            $query .= ' ' . $custom;

        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        if ($statement->execute($param))
            return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This question is suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ To answer your question there's single responsibility principle violated i.e. `db` class is responsible for building query, connecting to database, retrieving data from database and process it. Also it has hidden dependency on some config file.

Comment: Your design is fine - _game_ is not _db_ and thus should not `inherit` from _db_ - but it uses _db_ and it's perfectly good to store _db_ instance in field in _game_ class. Passing _db_ instance to the `constructor` of _game_ is also fine. Your code is a nice example of basic `OOP`.

Comment: Belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You could pass an existing PDO connection into the `db` class instead of creating it inside. It's more of a DB helper class actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't extend the DB class, but I also wouldn't instantiate it in some constructor. Instead use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and pass the DB object to the constructor:

```
class game {

    protected $db;

    function __construct( db $db ) {
        $this->db = $db
    }

}
```

Instantiation:

```
/* global variable database or from object storage */
$database = new db( /* … */ );

$game = new Game( $database );
```

You could extend the PDO class to implement user functions. That way you can pass around a PDO object and also make your own select function available.

```
class db extends \PDO {
    /* … */
}
```

Comment: +1, It's more better to use a different class for connection and instantiate connection from outside the `db` class and pass the new connection object to the `db` class as a dependency injection so you can use different drivers (mysql...) for `db` class easily.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to game::__construct() must be an instance of db, none given